# Searching for substring in element in a list an deleting the element

Tags: python, list, search, element, substring

I have a list and I am trying to delete the elements that have `'pie'` in them. This is what I've done:

```
['applepie','orangepie', 'turkeycake']
for i in range(len(list)):
    if "pie" in list[i]:
         del list[i]
```

I keep getting list index out of range, but when I change the `del` to a `print` statement it prints out the elements fine.

Comment: If `'pie'` is always at the end you can use the `endswith` method of strings. It would be more efficient(for long strings, for short strings it'll be almost the same) and clearer if that's what you want to do. (on a side note: also `startswith` exist).

Answer (score 6):

Instead of removing an item from the list you're iterating over, try creating a new list with Python's nice [list comprehension syntax](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
foods = ['applepie','orangepie', 'turkeycake']
pieless_foods =  [f for f in foods if 'pie' not in f]
```

Comment: `foods = ['applepie','orangepie', 'turkeycake']

pie_foods =  [f for f in foods if 'pie' not in f]`

(not sure if 'not in' is the right syntax.

Comment: @AJ. Thanks, got the sense the wrong way round - I've corrected that

Comment: Very short and compact answer. Would be the simplest solution

Answer (score 2):

Deleting an element during iteration, changes the size, causing IndexError.

You can rewrite your code as (using List Comprehension)

```
L = [e for e in L if "pie" not in e]
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
stuff = ['applepie','orangepie', 'turkeycake']
stuff = [item for item in stuff if not item.endswith('pie')]
```

Modifying an object that you're iterating over should be considered a no-go.

Answer (score 1):

The reason to why you get a error is because you change the length of the list when you delete something!

Example:

```
first loop: i = 0, length of list will become 1 less because you delete "applepie" (length is now 2)
second loop: i = 1, length of list will now become just 1 because we delete "orangepie"
last/third loop: i = 2, Now you should see the problem, since i = 2 and the length of the list is only 1 (to clarify only list[0] have something in it!).
```

So rather use something like:

```
for item in in list:
    if "pie" not in item:
        new list.append(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another but longer way would be to note down the indexes where you encounter pie and delete those elements after the first for loop

Comment: You still have the same problem - unless you delete the elements in the reverse order. But this is still not efficient, as removing an element means all the later elements have to be shuffled along each time. Creating a new list is quite efficient, you are not copying the elements, just creating extra references to them.